# When using the turtle function in python, how can I generate a random dot color?

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

For a my class, I am tasked with programming a turtle function that is user controlled via the arrow keys. The function displays itself and then a mirror of itself with dots. Each dot should be a completely randomized color. So far, I have this:

```
from turtle import *
from random import randrange

FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 10
mirrorTurtle = Turtle()

def turnRight():
    global turtle
    global mirrorTurtle

    turtle.right(45)

def turnLeft():
    global turtle
    global mirrorTurtle

    turtle.left(45)

def randomColor(turtle):
    r = randrange(256)    # red component of color
    g = randrange(256)    # green component
    b = randrange(256)    # blue component

def move():
    colormode(255)
    global turtle
    global mirrorTurtle
    global moving

    if moving:
        for i in range(1):
            turtle.penup()
            mirrorTurtle.penup()
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.dot(20, "red")
            mirrorTurtle.dot(10, "blue")
            turtle.forward(1)
            mirrorTurtle.setpos(-turtle.xcor(), -turtle.ycor())
            ontimer(move, 1000 // FRAMES_PER_SECOND)

def start():
    global moving

    moving = True
    move()

def stop():
    global moving

    moving = False


def main():
    colormode(255)
    global turtle
    global mirrorTurtle

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    mirrorTurtle.hideturtle()


    onkey(turnRight, "Right")
    onkey(turnLeft, "Left")
    onkey(start, "Up")
    onkey(stop, "Down")
    listen()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the issue for me is, where I have "red" and "blue" are supposed to be random colors (that still act as a mirror (i.e.; if the first dot typed is blue, the mirror should be blue as well).

Comment: This is _very_ unclear.

Comment: Without colormode(...): color("#"+"".join([random.choice("0123456789ABCDEF" for i in range(6)])

Comment: If I understood right.

Comment: the problem that i am having is hwo to generate a random color inside of the dot function. I know how to generate random colors using randrange, but inside the dot function, colors are entered as strings.

Comment: See comment above and don't use colormode.

Comment: Ok, see answer below ;-)

Comment: "*inside the dot function, colors are entered as strings*" -- Not according to [the turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.dot), which says that the `color` parameter may be "a colorstring or a numeric color tuple". As you can see in my answer, passing a numeric tuple works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a function that gives you a random color string, see this:

```
def randcolor():
    return "#"+"".join([random.choice("0123456789ABCDEF") for i in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to a solution. You need small changes to `randomColor` and to `move`.

In `randomColor`, you have successfully created three random numbers. Now you just need to create a `tuple` and return it, like so:

```
def randomColor():
    r = randrange(256)    # red component of color
    g = randrange(256)    # green component
    b = randrange(256)    # blue component
    return r,g,b
```

Then, you need to use that random color in your call to `dot()`:

```
        mirrorTurtle.dot(10, randomColor())
```

Additionally, to get your program to work in my environment, I need to add a call to `update()` at the end of `move()`, and a call to `mainloop()` at the end of `main()`.